# very basic javascript parameters issue

Tags: javascript, parameters

first question on stack overflow, I'm sure the answer is simple and I'm just overlooking something. The basic premise is that eventually this will be elaborated on so that the parameters that are passed into the functions will be generated by a user choosing from a number of options, but I cant even seem to make it work at this level.

The end goal is that all variables are taken and used in the final equation to generate an answer.

```
var first = function one(five) {
    return five;
};

var second = function two(thirty) {
    return ten;
};

var third = function three(ten) {
    return ten;
};

one(5);
two(30);
three(10);

var theanswer = first * second / third;
console.log(theanswer);
```

Thanks! I guess we all have to start somewhere.

Comment: second function should return thirty not ten

Comment: You need to use the name of the variables not the name of the functions.

Comment: I think you have mistaken `return`. That's not how you assign returned values from functions to a variable. You do it like: `var first = one(5);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you have for your function definitions is *named function expressions*. You are assigning a reference to the function to the variables, not the results of calling it.

Since you want the return value in those variables, assign it when you *call* the function, not when you define it.

You also need to return the right variable in `two`.

```
function one(five) {
    return five;
};

function two(thirty) {
    return thirty; 
};

function three(ten) {
    return ten;
};

var first = one(5);
var second = two(30);
var third = three(10);
```

Comment: thank you, its greatly appreciated. the end goal is really to use switches to return a different value depending on user input, but it looks like I'm getting ahead of myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

May be below code be a useful:

```
    var first = function one(five) {
        return five;
    };

    var second = function two(thirty) {
        return thirty;
    };

    var third = function three(ten) {
       return ten;
    };

   var theanswer = first(5) * second(30) / third(10);
   console.log(theanswer);
```